# Finding the points of intersection

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

Let f(x)  be a real valued function defined for all real numbers s such that $|f(x)-f(y)|  \leq (1/2)|x-y|$ for all $x,y$. Then what is the number of points of intersection of the graph of $y = f(x)$ and the line $y=x$?

Answer (score 5):

$f(x)$ is a contraction, so it has a unique fixed point by the contraction mapping theorem, that is a point where $f(x)=x$. So there is exactly one point where $y=f(x)=x$.

Comment: I understood your answer after some search on net . But I do no think that this is meant to solved like this , since the level of the knowledge approximated is high school mathematics ( with AP classes in calculus )

Comment: The proof of the contraction mapping theorem only uses concepts from high school calculus. It should be easy to see that there can be at most one intersection, if there were 2, $f(x_1)=x_1$ and $f(x_2)=x_2$, then $|f(x_1)-f(x_2)|=|x_1-x_2|$, which contradicts the assumption on $f(\cdot)$. You then just need to show there is a fixed point, which you can do by looking at the sequence $x_n=f(x_{n-1})$, $x_0=0$. It can be shown that this is a cauchy sequence, and the limit must be a fixed point because $x^*=\lim_{n\to \infty} x_n=f(\lim_{n \to \infty} x_{n-1})=f(x^*)$.